# Rotating image cuts corners

Tags: java, image, affinetransform

I'm currently looking into rotating images in Java, as I'm going to create some physics simulations where I need to rotate some sprites. I've managed to rotate pictures, but whenever I don't rotate exactly 90, 180 or 270 degrees the upper left corners of my image gets cut away. I read something somewhere about the centre of rotation not necessarily being (width/2, height/2), so I just tried some other parameters and almost got all corners, but the image's relative position to the panel has changed from centre to something else. Does anyone know what's doing this, and how I can work around it?

Here are three images showing what I'm talking about:

1. [Not rotated](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f23sgewx9nwjlow/one.PNG?dl=0)
2. [Rotated around (width/2, height/2)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/elkr2m4mahguz13/two.PNG?dl=0)
3. [Rotated around (width/2, height)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/anw2sf2q7bw2fh4/three.PNG?dl=0)

The code I use is the following:

```
@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        super.paintComponent(g2d);

        double rotate = Math.toRadians(45);
        double X = image.getWidth()/2;
        double Y = image.getHeight()/2;


        AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(rotate, X, Y);
        AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

        g2d.drawImage(op.filter(image, null), 200, 200, null);
    }
```

Might be worth mentioning that whatever angle, it's always the top left corner that gets cropped out.

**Edit:** So I've done some more testing, and if I rotate the square around a point which is (image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()/+20) the whole picture is displayed after rotation, but it's obviously no longer in the same position as before the rotation. What this tells me is that whatever "canvas" the post-processed image is being written to, is bigger on the X/Y axis that the image itself. I could probably write an algorithm to figure out how much the picture has moved on the X/Y axis and move it back to its original position, but this seems awfully complicated for something as "basic" as rotating something.

Answer (score 0):

i am pretty sure that your graphics object is smaller than your image...

when you create that panel on wich you draw, make it twice as large (ok, 1.5 times larger would also be sufficient) and make sure you rotate your image around the center of the graphics ... then your image will be painted properly!

Unluckily you haven't provided enough code to verify my theory... maybe you can add that part where you create the container or even better you test my theory and confirm it or prove it be wrong...

Sorry no code attached this time...